# Unable to build application in openshift

Tags: debian, openshift, apt-get

our container application is based on the image : php:7.3.1-apache

Debian apt source file says

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main
```

Recently a network security policy has been implemented so that only https traffic is allowed in our environment. Due to this our builds are not working as the apt connecting via http. Is there any official https repository available for stretch distribution that we can use in the image. I have tried changing the http with https in current source.list file but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Install the apt-transport-https package. Then you can use HTTPS.

Note: Not all Debian repositories support HTTPS. Some do not have real SSL certificates (self-signed). This can be a problem for you. At this date, I find it bizarre that some updates are happening with HTTP endpoints.